# come up with a python code to solve the following problem

Tags: python

Suppose the coverprice of a book is $24.95, but book stores get a 40% discount. Shipping costs $3 for the ﬁrst copy and 75 cents for each additional copy. What is the total wholesale cost for 60 copies?

This is what i have tried:

```py
    a='coverprice'
    >>> b='discount'
    >>> c='shipping costs'
    >>> d='additional copies'
    >>> e='no. of copies'
    >>> a=24.95
    >>> b=0.4
    >>> c=3
    >>> d=0.75*59
    >>> e=60
    >>> print ('total costs=',c+d)
    total costs= 47.25
    >>> f='total cost'
    >>> print ('total discount=',b*a)
    total discount= 9.98
    >>> g='total discount'
    >>> print('total purchase cost before discount=',a*e)
    total purchase cost before discount= 1497.0
    >>> h='total purchase cost before discount'
    >>> print('total purchase cost after discount=',h-g)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
    >
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why is this labelled PHP? Is this a school project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

is because you tried to subtract strings instead of numbers:

```
>>> g='total discount'
...
>>> h='total purchase cost before discount'
>>> print('total purchase cost after discount=',h-g)
```

Given the problem described, and approach taken, I might go about it this way:

```
a = 24.95  # cover price
b = 0.4  # discount
c = 3.00  # initial shipping cost
d = 0.75  # additional items shipping cost
e = 60  # no. of copies

f = c + d * (e - 1)  # total shipping cost
print(f"total shipping cost = ${f:0,.2f}")

g = a * b  # discounted book cost
print(f"discounted book cost = ${g:0,.2f}")

h = a * e  # total purchase cost before discount (sans shipping)
print(f"total purchase cost before discount (sans shipping) = ${h:0,.2f}")

i = g * e  # total purchase cost after discount (sans shipping)
print(f"total purchase cost after discount (sans shipping) = ${i:0,.2f}")

j = h - i  # total discounted savings
print(f"total discounted savings = ${j:0,.2f}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
total shipping cost = $47.25
discounted book cost = $9.98
total purchase cost before discount (sans shipping) = $1,497.00
total purchase cost after discount (sans shipping) = $598.80
total discounted savings = $898.20
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great scenario where python comes in handy in our daily lives, and it is also a good to learn about the python operators:

```
old_price = 24.95 # Set a variable for the old price
new_price = old_price * 0.6 # Set a variable for the new price
first_copy = 3 # Set a variable for the price of shipping fee for the first copy
other_copies = 0.75 * 59 # Calxulate the price of shipping fee for the following copies
whole_sales = new_price * 60 + first_copy + other_copies # Calculate the total price
print(round(whole_sales,2)) # Print the total price, rounded to the nearest cent
```